# In RDL report how can I move tablix rows down?

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, rdl, dynamics-al

In RDL report I have a tablix that is half the pages width (there is another tablix on another side of the page) and if I do not print one row, other rows move up, what I need is if I don't print one row other rows to move down. Essentially, I want bottom of my tablix to not have a gap between it ant another tablix bellow it. Is it plausible to do so?

I tried making the table full width of the page, and then there is no gap, but I can not have data side by side from two tablixes

EDIT:
I have this tablix
[Tablix printig example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTaG4.png)

If I do not print one of the lines other lines move up
[Tablix printing example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzQ0E.png)

What I would like is for them to stay down by the next tablix or move down if I don't print one of the bottom rows

Comment: Please [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78100158/edit) your question and provide more info. Show what you have now and what you want. At the moment it's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: try putting the top tablix in a rectangle and setting `ConsumerContainerWhietSpace` to `True` in the report properties.